# How to substring graphems from String?

Tags: java, substring, breakiterator

I try to substring 5 graphems from String and cant make it properly.
I have such String:

My last try was with BreakIterator:

```
public String truncate(String input) {
        BreakIterator it = BreakIterator.getCharacterInstance();
        it.setText(input);
        String res = "";
        for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
            res += printAt(it,i,input);        
        return res;
    }

    public static String printAt(BreakIterator boundary, int pos, String source) {
        int end = boundary.following(pos);
        int start = boundary.previous();
        return source.substring(start,end);
    }
```

Can anybody help me with this task?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it possible to mention what is the expected input and expected output and what is your current output and why does the string look like card

Comment: As a result I need to substring only first 5 cards in String.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your input contains special characters expressed in Unicode thus you should work with code points.
See an example of a `substringByCodepoint(String inputStr, int codePointStart, int codePointEnd)` method implementation [here](http://www.java2s.com/example/java-utility-method/string-sub-string/substringbycodepoint-string-inputstr-int-codepointstart-int-codepointend-d5d78.html).